# If a language is contained in other langauge, is it of the same complexity?

Tags: turing-machines, computability, complexity-classes

If some language $L$ is in **P**, and some other language $K$ is contained in $L$, does that mean that $K$ is also in **P**?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

No. $\Sigma^*\in\mathbf{P}$ and every langauge is a subset of that – even undecidable ones.